# My Python3 REST JSON API via requests is not working

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to receive JSON Data from a REST API which authorizes via base64.

Sadly, my code below is not working. 
I'm quite new to programming with python3... well with programming at all....

I have tried the code i posted and some code with http.client+pandas.
But both are not working fully. And I'm not quite sure what's **the best way I should go**.

with requests: 
in the payload variable no values are stored. The connection is ok (r == 200)

```
import requests
import base64
import json
import csv

url = 'www.url.com/api/get?per_page=50'
UserAndPass = base64.b64encode(b"user:12345").decode("ascii")
payload = {'some':'data'}

headers = { 
'content-type': "application/json",
'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % UserAndPass
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

with http.client:
The way via http.client fails on the load() function. loads() is working, but i don't understand why (loads = strings, load = bytes) Additionally: With loads() the JSON (result) looks weird. It's not really structured like i would expect. How can i change the way the "columns" are beeing created?

```
import http.client
import base64
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.url.com")
UserAndPass = base64.b64encode(b"user:12345").decode("ascii")

headers = { 
'content-type': "application/json",
'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % UserAndPass
}

conn.request("GET", "/api/get?per_page=50", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
raw_data = res.read()
jdata = json.load(raw_data)    
result = pd.DataFrame(jdata)
```

i want to receive the data, into a json. end-outcome should be a .csv or .xls with data (orders from a shop)

the json data I receive from the api looks like this:

```
{
        "id": 400285,
        "statusId": 1,
        "statusName": "Open",
        "totalSum": "1.337,00 EUR",
        "purchaseDate": "2019-06-28 21:45:10",
        "comment": "",
        "withdrawalIds": [],
        "mailStatus": true,
        "customerId": 1,        
        "customerMemos": [],
        "deliveryAddress": {
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "company": "Testshop 2",
            "street": "Teststr. 1",
            "houseNumber": "",
            "additionalAddressInfo": "",
            "postcode": "12345",
            "city": "Testort",
            "state": "NRW",
            "country": "Germany",
            "countryIsoCode": "DE"
        }
},
```

BR

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Elaborate your question a little bit.

Comment: i've updated my questions :).
requests: payload is not beeing filled
http.client: load() is not working

Comment: does anyone have an idea?